# Do American and British English speakers understand the phrase ''to make a hames of sth''?

Tags: dialects, hiberno-english

This phrase is used in Ireland (Hiberno English).

It means to make a mess of something. Interestingly enough, everyone in Ireland knows what this phrase means but very few actually know what a hames actually is.

Note: The word hames is pronounced to rhyme with games and names.

Examples:

I made a complete hames of my exam today, I definitely won't pass.

The first time I tried to make sushi I made an absolute hames of it, but I'm much better now.

Wow, the hairdresser really made a hames of your bangs, you should have demanded a refund.

I had to look up the origin of the term hames.

Seemingly a hames is an object you secure on a horse to help carry a load of goods. When the hames is poorly secured then the load can easily all fall off which of course would be a bit of a disaster.

Comment: I'm an educated North American and I've never encountered either the word _hames_  nor the phrase containing it. I presume it's pronounced something like [heimz]?

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, yeah it rhymes with ''games''.

Comment: You've mentioned the *hame* related to an equine contrivance. The OED says that one first appeared around 1300 but they aren't perfectly certain where it came from. An older word *hame* meaning a skin or integument like a sloughed off snake or dragon skin dates from Old English, but stopped being used after the 16th century. Any chance yours is more related to the older term than to the newer?

Comment: Not that there is any connection but the meaning is reminiscent of 'to make a hash of something'.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.dailyedge.ie/make-a-hames-of-it-saying-3215325-Jan2017/%3Famp%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwjlkoeA7oTxAhXK4KQKHXZZAqEQFjABegQIJBAC&usg=AOvVaw0MVv_MrOK3O783_GscTV0P&ampcf=1

Comment: I hear this word frequently. It never crossed my mind that it was Hiberno-English until now!  I'm in NI by the way :-)

Comment: No, generally folks in other countries don't know phrases in dialects in other countries. Why would they?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Education. Educated English speakers understand phrases from other dialects that they would never use themselves or never hear in their home country.

Comment: @Kantura See the first comment here.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Well education doesn't mean one knows everything, just that ones knowledge and experience is broadened. I am aware of many phrases unique to various other English dialects. I certainly don't know every phrase in every dialect.